# Remove left and right side space of line chart in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using react-chartjs2 in react application. I want to remove extra space as follow in this image.

[image]

Here are my chart configuration options

```
// chart options
const options = {
  legend: {
        display: false
    },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        color: ChartConfig.chartGridColor,
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        fontColor: ChartConfig.axesColor,
        beginAtZero:true,
        min: 0
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero:true,
        min: 0,
        padding: 0,
        display: false
      },
      gridLines: {
        drawTicks: false,
        drawBorder: false
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Any link to demo ?

Comment: I have no demo yet. I'm working on locally.

Comment: Please create one, and provide link to the npm package

Comment: maybe it has to do with this bug: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5433